# Back Stack, Splash and TabActivity

Tags: android

I've searched SO and found several answers to the question in general, and have tried them all and am not having success.  I really don't have my head around how the back stack works, Intent flags or the finish method.  Here's my setup:

On application start-up, there's a splash screen where a couple AsyncTasks run in the background and check a couple webservers for updated content.  ProgressDialogs report status.  When complete (via the last onPostExecute), I launch a new Activity ("Home").  This seems to reflect some of the other posts, but I think my kludge is due to Home being a TabActivity, with 4 tabs, that initially calls setCurrentTab on tab 0.

So, using the suggestions previously posted:

1. android:noHistory="true" on the Splash activity
2. calling Splash.this.finish() after it launches the Home TabActivity
3. setting the Home TabActivity intent flag of Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
4. setting the Home TabActivity intent flag of Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

The users sees the splash, the TabActivity launches, *the user clicks to another tab*, then hits back - the application closes (not force close - just closes back to the devices home screen).

If I don't use any of those, when the user hits back after changing to another tab, they go back to the Splash screen and are stuck (I could add a button or something to take them to the Home TabActivity but that's not optimal).

The desired result is that the user sees the Splash, gets taken to the Home TabActivity, clicks another tab, then hits back, he should be taken back to the initially set tab (tab 0).

Any insight is appreciated.

TYIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back stack is actually officially called the activity stack - every time you start an activity, that gets pushed onto the top of the stack (unless you set one of those flags you mentioned).

This means that unless each tab in your main app is a separate activity, then the default back key behaviour will be to leave your main app activity.

You can control this by [taking over the back key](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html#taking_over_back_key) or by overriding the tab switching behaviour to start different activities.